# Memory leak question between 3.4.0 and 4.0

Tags: lightningchart

When I ran this [example](https://lightningchart.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/edit/lcjs-example-0028-multiChannelLineProgressiveOwnAxes.html?disable-animations=1&isList=true) in v3.4.0 with vue, there is a memory leak. JS heap memory keeps increasing.
But I didn't find this problem when I ran it directly in the web example(v4.0).

Is there is a memory leak in version 3.x?

I only found this about performance improvement in 4.x on the official website.
[image: 4.x performance improvement]

Comment: I'm not aware of any memory leaks in this example. Maybe you can clarify how you found it. For example, how long the application was ran, and how the heap memory progressed.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Well, maybe it's something else.  Anyway, this problem disappeared after I upgraded 4.2.0.